# Firefox Can't Read Fetch Response Header

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, fetch-api

I'm trying to use the fetch API to send requests in my application, and if I get a `401 Unauthorized` response, I want to read the value of the `WWW-Authenticate` response header. This works fine on Chrome, but on Firefox, I'm unable to see the `WWW-Authenticate` header, even though it's included in the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header of my response.

My code:

```js
const api = async (endpoint, fetchOptions) => {
  // fetchOptions:
  // {
  //   "credentials": "same-origin",
  //   "method": "GET",
  //   "headers": {
  //     "Accept": "application/json",
  //     "Content-Type": "application/json"
  //   }
  // }

  const response = await fetch(endpoint, fetchOptions)
    .catch(r => r)
    .then(r => { r.headers.forEach(console.log.bind(console)); return r; });

  // handle 401 errors
  if (!response.status === 401 && response.headers.has('WWW-Authenticate')) {
    const authenticate = response.headers.get('WWW-Authenticate');
    const authEndpoint = authenticate.match(/authorization_endpoint="([^"]+)/i)[1];

    window.location.href = authEndpoint;
    return;
  }
};
```

My request:

```
GET /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
```

My response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: WWW-Authenticate
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="http://localhost:3001", authorization_endpoint="<oauth endpoint>"
Bearer
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcYXNjaW50ZXJuXFNvdXJjZVxSZXBvc1xQb3J0YWxcQVBJXFNhbXMuV2ViQXBpXGFwaVxsb2dpbg==?=
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 13:37:08 GMT
Content-Length: 128
```

Console output:

```
no-cache cache-control 
application/json content-type 
-1 expires 
no-cache pragma
```

Does anyone know why Firefox wouldn't be able to read that response header?

Comment: Have you tried also sending a 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' response header?

Comment: @sideshowbarker no dice, same console output

Comment: did a little more testing and this seems to be specific to the name of the header I'm trying to use. when adding my data to "X-WWW-Authenticate" instead, I'm able to see it in firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a known bug with multiple WWW-Authenticate response headers, you might be hitting that: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1491010.